# Compiling resources.qrc

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, qgis

I am trying to follow this tutorial here:

https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/building_a_python_plugin.html

However, running `pb_tool compile` gives me an error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/pyrcc5', '-o', 'resources.py', 'resources.qrc']' returned non-zero exit status 127.
```

I am very new to pyqt, qgis, etc., so I don't really know what to do here. My system is macOS Catalina

Comment: A 127 exit status usually means that the command has not been found (pyrcc5, in this case, which should have been installed . Have you correctly followed the [instructions](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/building_a_python_plugin.html#python-bindings-for-qt) for your system?